# Angular2 sharing services across modules without exact import statement

Tags: angular

Recently I fell in love with Angular2/4 but currently I'm struggling with first major doubt on designs.

Please consider following `Shared` module, that I'd like to export shared common components (i.e. my custom buttons and other "atomic" building block components) and common **services** as well:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {ExampleService } from './services/example.service';
import { Component1Component } from './component1/component1.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    Component1Component,
],
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    exports: [Component1Component],
    providers: [ExampleService],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Inside this particular module it's components (in example Component1Component) are able to use ExampleService (because it's `providers` array presence), but even that, it's still has to be referenced directly as `import` statement inside component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {ExampleService} from './../services/example.service'; //THIS LINE BOTHERS ME    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

  data: string;

  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.exampleService.exampleLog();
  }
}
```

While components inside common module may direct this service relatively easy (because path would be usually short and coherent like `./../services/service_name` and they will be placed in same `shared` module folder but what if I would like to use this service in parent module?
Consider module, where we are importing our defined common module:

```
//Angular modules
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

//App modules
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module'; //WE IMPORT DEFINED MODULE WITH SERVICES IN HIS PROVIDERS ARRAY

//App components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule //IMPORTS ARRAY WITH OUR MODULE
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, I'd like to use my service in `AppComponent`. I assumed, that if we importing dedicated module to handle service dependencies (i.e. `SharedModule`) we don't need to bother with direct service integration into components later on. But unfortunately, even thought we say to Angular just couple minutes ago: "Hey, Angular, this is `ExampleService` it's located in this ant this path and will be distributed with shared module by placing it into `providers` array." and we define following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService){} //HERE ALL IDEA CRASHES FOR ME

  title = 'app';
}
```

Angular is unable to recognize `ExampleService` as the service we plug into `SharedModule`. We must manually add an `import` statement, which might be this time completely mangled out of context (i.e. `./../../../shared/services/example.service.ts`).

So the question would be: why to bother with `providers`, `@Injectable`, modules definition and all that a bit painful stuff if at the end of the day you still need to guide angular by hand and point him directly, what particular service you wish to use? How does it come in pair with all dependency injection theorem, if we have to know **exact** implementation of service we wish to inject (because we have to know **exact** url to .ts service file).

if such problem was very gently resolved in components (i.e. I'm able to use `<app-component1></app-component1>` markups in importing module component, why in case of shared services it must be such pain?

As disclosure, I understand that `import` of modules/pipes/services at top-most of files plays completely different role than imports array of angular component. Sorry for long post, I just hope I stated my doubts clear enough to justify it.